# msgsnd Invalid argument

Tags: c++, ipc, msgsend

With the following code:

```
#define MSGLEN 128

typedef struct {
long id;
char message[MSGLEN];
} data;

data msg;

msgsnd(msg_id, &msg, MSGLEN, IPC_NOWAIT);
```

I get an Invalid argument error, but

```
msgsnd(msg_id, &msg.message, MSGLEN, IPC_NOWAIT);
```

is working.
Of course I created the message que with `msgget` and `kernel.msgmax = 65536`

Comment: can you provide some of the code in which you make this call, for context?

Answer (score 1):

OK... my fault. For everyone who encounters the same problem:

```
msg.id = 1;
```

The id must be greater than 0.